# How to make delete or put requests with user input in node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm trying to make an CRUD api using express and mongoose. I have an html form, and i managed to make the GET and POST requests but I can't do the DELETE and PUT with html form. I know that html5 and browsers don't support the DELETE and PUT method, but how do websites handle them? Do they only use POST and GET methods? I read on an article that it's not recommended to use POST requests for purposes other that creating because of caches and cookies. And I don't want to handle them with AJAX calls.
app.js(server-side):

```
app.delete("/deleteItem/:name", (req, res)=>{
    //delete the item from database
});
app.put("/updateItem", (req, res)=>{
   //get the req.query or req.body and update the item in database
});
```

index.html

```
<!--this is for POST requests-->
<form method="POST" action="/addItem">
    <input type="text" name="itemName" required/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<!--if DELETEwas supported ->
<form method="DELETE" action="/deleteItem">
    <input type="text" name="itemName" required/>
    <!--I want to get the value of the itemName field in order to delete it in server side using mongoose-->
    <input type="Submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>

<!--if PUT was supported ->
<form method="DELETE" action="/deleteItem">
    <input type="text" name="itemName" required/>
    <!-- inputs.... -->
    <!-- I want to get the values of the input fields in  order to update the item in server side using mongoose-->
    <input type="Submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Briefly, what i want to know is whether there is a way to get the values of the inputs without using POST.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use **method-override** middleware: https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was helpful.

Comment: I found out another way thanks to the link you put in the comment: I reassigned the value of `req.method` to `DELETE` in a middleware on the route i wish to do the operation `deleteItem` and it worked. `app.use("/deleteItem", (req, res,next)=>{
 req.method = "DELETE"
 next();
});` I want to know if i will encounter some problems instead of using the `method-override` module?

Comment: but this way you need to redefine this middleware for every route and every other method like PUT, PATCH and.... **method-override**, in a nutshell, does the same thing ( [replacing `req.method`](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override/blob/5b83d4f0dc3db414df6c7e4a5da93dec170153de/index.js#L73-L79) ) but in a much more flexible and secure way. Also gives clients the option to send the desired method whether via a *custom header* or as a *query parameter*.

Comment: Okay. It's just if i understood well the concept of method-override. Thank you for the help.